# Django rjust filter with fillchar

Tags: django, templates

Possible to do this in a Django template tag?  {{ string_field.rjust(8, '0') }}

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: No. You'll have to [write a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). It's easy. Or you'll have to do `rjust` in your view and pass that variable to your templates.

Answer (score 1):

Django [rjust filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#rjust) doesnot accept a fillchar. But you can achieve what you want by [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) and [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) operations.

```
{{ "A00000000" | add:string_field | slice:"-8:"}}
```

**EDIT:**
A in the above string "A00000000" is added to prevent it to be converted to an integer.
From [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add):
[image]

Comment: This works if `string_field` is not an integer. Because then Django will convert it into `int` and sum it like - `000000 + string_field`. The end result will not have the leading zeroes.

Comment: @xyres: Thanks for catching that. I have updated my answer to take care of that.

Comment: It's a pretty creative solution.